# What should be the response of GET for multiple requested resources with some invalid ids?

Tags: rest, http, spring-mvc, get, api-design

what should be the response to a request to 
`http://localhost:8080/users/1,2,3` when the system doesn't have a user with id 3?

When all users are present I return a `200` response code with all user objects in the response body. When the user requests a single missing user I return a `404` with an error message in the body.

However, what should be the body and status code for a mix between valid and missing ids?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to follow REST API principles. In order to keep clear api design you should rather use query string for filtering

```
http://localhost:8080/users?id=1,2,3
```

Then you won't have such dilemmas - you can return just only users with id contained in provided value list and 200 status code (even if list is empty). This endpoint in general

```
http://localhost:8080/users/{id}
```

should be reserved for requesting single resource (user) by providing primary key.

Comment: Careful there: the query part is still part of the resource identity. See [RFC 3986, section 3.4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.4).

Answer (score 0):

What you are requesting there is a *collection*. The request essentially reads: "give me all users whose ID is in {1, 2, 3}." A subset of those users (let's say there is no user yet with the ID 3) would still be a successful operation, which is asking for a [200 (OK)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1).

If you are overly concerned by this, there's still the possibility to redirect the client via [303 (See Other)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.4) to a resource representation without the offending elements.

If all of the IDs are invalid, things get a bit tricky. One may be tempted to simply return a [404 (Not Found)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4), but strictly speaking that were not correct:

> The 404 status code indicates that the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource

Indeed, there is one: The empty set. From a programmatic standpoint, it may indeed be easier to just return that instead of throwing an error. This relies on clients being able to process empty sets/documents.

The RFC grants you the freedom to go either way:

> […] the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or *is not willing to disclose that one exists*.

So if you wish to hide the existence of an empty set, it's okay. It bears mentioning that a set containing nothing is not nothing itself ;)

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend not to offer the method in the first place, but rather force the user of your APIto make three separate requests and return unambiguous responses (two `200`s for users 1 and 2 and `404` for user 3). Additionally, the API could offer a get method that responds with all available user ids or such (depends on your system).

Alternatively, if that's not an option, I guess, you have two options:

1. Return `404` as soon as one user is not found, which technically is more accurate in my opinion. I mean, the request was for **1, 2 AND 3**, which was not found.
2. Return `200` with users 1 and 2, and null, which probably is the most useful for your scenario.